# How can I incorporate Python scripts into my website? Do I need a framework?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm wondering if there's a good way for me to incorporate Python scripts into my current website.

I have a personal website & my own server that I have been working with for a while. So far it's just been html / css / javascript. I have made a Python script in the past that uses another website's API to retrieve something that I would like to display on my website. I've only used Python from the terminal to take input and spit out results. Is there a way for me to run a Python script from javascript through Ajax to get some content back?

I don't really want to use a framework like Django or Flask because I feel as though those are mostly for entire projects. I only want to use one Python script on one page for my website. Is this even something I should do? Any advice would be great.

Comment: Have a look at http://airpair.com/python/posts/django-flask-pyramid

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. If anyone comes across this question and wants to know what I ended up doing, I used php to communicate with my python script through ajax. In php I used the 'system' command to run the python script as a shell command basically.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using only javascript and don't feel like a framework is the solution, you'd better rewrite your python script using javascript. These two languages have a lot in common and most of the stuff are transferable. Calling python from javascript would most likely not going to work that great. Again, unless you share your python script(which is encouraged in SO because text only question does not quite fit in here), all answers are opinion based.

Comment: You're right, all the answers are opinion based, but it is important to consider if you want to compute the logic on server-side(scripting languages) or client-side (javascript). Probably @dan need some operation server-side and for this reason he's asking about python

Answer (score 2):

I completly agree with you about Django, but I think you can give a chance to Flask, it is really light and I can be used for many porpouses. Anyway if you want to call a python scripts you need a way to call it. I think you need a "listener" for the script for example a service or a web service (for this reason I think Flask can be an really easy solution).
Be careful about calling the script, a web service can be reachable from the frontend but this can not be done from a "standard" script.
My suggestion is take a look at Flask is more light that you think.

Answer (score 2):

Give a chance to Flask!
It's designed for the micro service that you just described.

Here is what you could do with less than 30 lines of code:

**app.py (flask file)**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import jsonify, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='.', static_folder='.', static_url_path='')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
def convert():
    return jsonify(items=[
        ("whatever python function output that you have")
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html file**

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/convert',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var el = $('#req_result');

                for (let item of data.items) {
                   ### show your result here ###
                  }
                }

                $('#req_hide').hide();
                el.show();
            }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation to use Flask! I might as well try it. I have one question about this... The ajax url is '/convert' which is in your app.route in your example. How does it get to your app.py file to use that route? is it injected in the html somewhere or something like that?